# How do I read from a public fixed byte in IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

In C# I have an attribute declared as:

```
public fixed byte foo[10]
```

In client code I'm see it uses this function to convert to string:

```
public static unsafe string GetString(byte* byteArray)
{
  return new String((sbyte*)byteArray);
}
```

In IronPython printing it given me the type as a string:

```
>>> print obj.foo
Baz+<foo>e__FixedBuffer1
```

Trying to use the conversion function gives an error.

```
>>> print GetString(obj.foo)
expected Byte*, got <Foo>e__FixedBuffer1
```

What is the correct way read this attribute in IronPython?

Comment: What is cchar? I can't find a reference for what it's supposed to be. Or did you just mean char?

Comment: cchar is byte, he forgot to put using cchar = System.Byte; in the question.
replace his public fixed cchar foo[10]
with public fixed byte foo[10]

Comment: I changed the question to using `byte`.

Comment: Also seeing unmatched parens in the `return`, might want to clear it up to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed fields in .NET are quite special. A fixed field that you have (`public fixed byte foo[10]`) gets compiled into a special nested struct and the type of your fixed field is changed into that nested struct. In short, this:

```
public fixed byte foo[10];
```

Gets compiled into this:

```
// This is the struct that was generated, it contains a field with the
// first element of your fixed array
[CompilerGenerated, UnsafeValueType]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 10)]
public struct <foo>e__FixedBuffer0
{
    public byte FixedElementField;
}

// This is your original field with the new type
[FixedBuffer(typeof(byte), 10)]
public <foo>e__FixedBuffer0 foo;
```

You can see this for yourself with a tool like ILSpy.

Now, if your code in C# has a line `GetString(obj.foo)` it is compiled into:

```
GetString(&obj.foo.FixedElementField);
```

So it literally takes the address of the first element of your array and passes it as the parameter to the method (thus the `GetString` parameter is of the correct type, `byte*`).

When you call the same method with the same parameter in IronPython the parameter type is still the type of your field: `<foo>e__FixedBuffer0`, which cannot be cast to `byte*` (obviously). The correct method of making this method call would be to do the same substitution as the C# compiler does - take the address of the `FixedElementField` and pass it to the `GetString`, but unfortunately, Python (to my knowledge) does not have an analog to the `&` operator in C#.

The conclusion would be: you cannot directly access a fixed field from IronPython. I would say that your best bet is to have a "proxy" method like:

```
public string GetFooString(Baz baz)
{
    return new string((sbyte*)baz.foo);
}
```

PS I am not an IronPython pro, so maybe there is a super-way to directly access the foo prop, but I just do not see how.